# What is the Azure warmup UserAgent string in 2018?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, warm-up, application-warmup

1. This source says **Initialization**:

   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2843964/application-initialization-module-fails-when-web-site-requires-ssl
2. Then this site says **SiteWarmup**:

   http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/

   (being referenced by David Ebbo himself: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2583)
3. Then this one says **IIS Application Initialization Warmup**:

   https://www.jan-v.nl/post/warming-up-your-app-service

I was using **SiteWarmup** but I recently large significant warmup problems. Has anything be changed here recently?

Where can you find the 'official' documentation - that I can double check. I would expect it with bold letters somewhere in Azure, because https is *the* standard nowadays, and it doesn't work out of the box with https (or redirects in general).

Answer (score 1):

While I can't find it mentioned in the official docs either, today when swapping deployment slots in Azure my logs tell me the user agent is `IIS Application Initialization Warmup`.

Comment: Has anyone confirmed if this is correct?